# What is Data connection Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-data-connections, data-connection, project-site

- What is the data connection library in SharePoint online?

what is the relation between the Infopath & data connection - library?

- When to use a data connection library?
- What are the uses and advantages of the data connection library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is the data connection library in SharePoint online?**

Simply, it's a SharePoint library that holds Data connection files. these files contain information about **external data connections**.

> **Note:** In SharePoint On-prem, the Data connection is only available with SharePoint Enterprise Edition, for more details, check [Missing data connection library in
>   SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/21/missing-data-connection-library-in-sharepoint/)

**what is the relation between the Infopath & data connection library?**

To work with InfoPath, you must have a data connection between your form and the data source,

This data connection file is created through data connection wizard in InfoPath designer.

This `data connection file` must be stored in **Data connection library** and can't be stored in any other document library type.

**When to use a data connection library?**

If you are working with `InfoPath` or `Excel services`, you should have data connection library to store the generated data connection files :)

**What are the advantages of the data connection library?**

- **Deployment to Different Environments:** Test and production servers can specify different locations for data access and a form template will automatically use the server-specific location when they are published to that server.
- **Reconfiguration:** Data connection settings, such as database server locations, can be modified independently of the solutions that use them.
- **Cross-domain security:** only connections specified by using the DCL can retrieve data from outside the farm.